# A build of GUI Emacs for OS X that can display emoji?

Tags: osx

Is there a build of **GUI** Emacs for Mac that can display emoji? I tried [this](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and AquaEmacs but neither of them could display it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Emacs Mac Port](https://github.com/railwaycat/mirror-emacs-mac) is said to support emoji display out of the box:

> - Can display color bitmap fonts such as Apple Color Emoji, if
>     compiled and executed on Mac OS X 10.7 or later.  Also supports
>     display of some combinations of regional indicator symbols, such
>     as U+1F1EF followed by U+1F1F5, as national flags.  Variation
>     Selectors 15 (text-style) and 16 (emoji-style) are also supported.
>     On OS X 10.10.3 and later, emoji modifiers for skin tones (U+1F3FB - U+1F3FF) are supported as well.

It's available in a [Homebrew Tap](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport).  To enable the tap and install the port, type:

```
$ brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport
$ brew install emacs-mac
```

---

Alternatively you can manually configure the Emacs' font choice to use Apple's Emoji font:

```
(set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji")
                  frame 'prepend)
```

Note that you'll need to apply this to every new frame, and thus call it in a function for `after-make-frame-functions`.

This should work on a normal Cocoa build of standard Emacs, e.g. from `brew install emacs` or [Emacs for Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com).

Comment: The Emacs Mac port by YAMAMOTO Mitsuharu is available in MacPorts too (run `port install emacs-mac-app`).

Comment: I use the railwaycat port, and can confirm firsthand that it does display emoji in the Apple Color Emoji font.

Comment: Also, for the benefit of people who stumble on this question and are trying to make emoji work on something other than a Mac: [emacs-emojify](https://github.com/iqbalansari/emacs-emojify) is a cross-platform emoji library that includes a broad collection of (I presume) free emoji in .png format, and I find it works very nicely on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I tried Homebrew Tap but how can I run the installed railwaycat emacs? It's not supposed to run on Terminal, is it? If so, I wouldn't be able to click to navigate.  I also tried the alternative method, adding a new function including the snippet you wrote and then hooking it to after-make-frame-functions in my init.el file, but didn't work? It just gives me an error saying "wrong number of arguments."

Comment: @stacko Like any other OS X application: Start the app bundle.  Run `brew linkapps` to have it appear in Launchpad, etc.  As for the alternative method, the error message doesn't help without seeing what you've done.  Take a look at the docstring of `after-make-frame-functions` to figure out how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: How can I read the docstring of `after-make-frame-functions`?

Comment: @stacko Uh, `C-h v after-make-frame-functions`?

Comment: Isn't this what you meant in your alternative method?: `(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-set-font)
 (defun my-set-font ()
 (interactive)
 (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji") frame 'prepend))`  I tried this as I said earlier and it didn't work. Am I taking what you wrote in your answer wrong?

Comment: @stacko Please, do read the docstring.  You'll see that the function is supposed to take an argument, namely the `frame`.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But how could you know that it's supposed to take "frame" as an argument? I looked at the docstring but it just said `after-make-frame-functions is a variable defined in ``frame.el'. Its value is (my-set-font select-frame)` Does the `select-frame` part mean it needs an argument `frame`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It did say  `The functions are run with one arg, the newly created frame` after that. : `This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
Documentation:
Functions to run after a frame is created.
The functions are run with one arg, the newly created frame.`

Comment: I found I had to run something like `(mapc '(lambda (f) (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji") f 'prepend)) (frame-list))` to apply this to the initially created frame.