# How can I display any Unicode character in GUI Emacs for OS X?

Tags: osx, unicode

I managed to make emacs dispaly any emoji in GUI Emacs for OS X thanks to the answer and comments [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20186/a-build-of-gui-emacs-for-os-x-that-can-display-emoji), but then I noticed I have other symbols that I can't display in Emacs like the because symbol "∵".

How can I set Emacs so that it can display any Unicode symbol?

I tried to set it so that it can display the because symbol in a new frame first by adding the snippet below to my init file, and it worked, but do I have to add a font-family for a specific symbol I found is not being displayed in Emacs one by one every time? I'm not even sure the new font family I just added, Arial Unicode MS, can display the rest of the unicode characters that emacs can't display by default.

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-set-font)
(defun my-set-font (frame)
  (interactive)

  (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji") frame 'prepend)
  (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Arial Unicode MS") frame 'prepend)

  )
```

Comment: Haven't checked on this, but I think it's mostly a matter of finding a font that can handle the unicode characters in question, and telling Emacs to use that one.

Comment: I don't know if I should retract this question or mark it as duplicate, but this seems to be the answer I was looking for: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/force-a-single-font-for-all-unicode-glyphs?rq=1 I just tried this and it seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I'll go ahead and mark it as a duplicate.